# Using Amplitube for iPad on stage

Tags: guitar-effects

Good afternoon,
I have recently started using my iPad with my Taylor acoustic guitar and can make it sound like a 65 Fender Twin reverb using the [Amplitube app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amplitube-free/id373309342?mt=8).

It sounds great but I was wondering if anybody else had used the iPad onstage and if there were any issues, for example latency problems?

Comment: The question as originally set was way too broad (there are hundreds of music apps for iPad), so I have edited it down to the specific one you had.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing about the stage *per se* that will introduce latency. So if it works at home it should work on stage. I use similar software on a desktop at home and excessive disk activity (rare for me) will cause audio glitches. However: if you add too many effects in a chain, you might overwhelm the CPU. I suspect the iPad app is limited by design and by CPU.

As someone who does NOT go on stage, I would SUSPECT you may have issues surrounding ruggedness and vibration since the neither the iPad nor the cabling is designed for wear and tear related to professional gigging.

Comment: iPads use SSDs (solid state harddrives), so vibrations won't matter. Also, if you want to plug other effects into the chain, just plug them into the chain after the iPad, so that it won't have to process the signal.

Comment: I've seen professionals on stage with iPads (for example, Bjork).

Comment: @ekaj by "too many effects in the chain", horatio probably means effects in the virtual chain within the iPad.

Comment: yes, I meant the simulated effects chain. However I probably would put the external effects BEFORE the ipad in the chain since the ipad in OP's situation is running an amp (and cabinet) simulator. Of course, whatever sounds the best.